# Join spark dataset with complex condition

Tags: apache-spark, join, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

Consider a bean as follows:

```
class Bean {
  String id;
  String joinColumn;
}
```

I have two datasets of this Bean and need to join them on joinColumn but the condition to join is not equals to.

I need to have a logic that compares joinColumn for equality, if not equal, modify the string based on some condition and check for equality. How should it be done using dataset API?

Comment: It would be useful to provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

1. Do `LEFT JOIN`- Elements that joined successfully will have data from both DSs. Other will have NULLs.
2. Store successfully joined data
3. Filter out successfully joined elements from output of 1
4. Modify the string based on your condition on the output of 3
5. Do `join` with output of 4
6. `Union` outputs of 5 and 2.